# How do I create a .php for my Google map that saves basic user content?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I have a basic map and it is set up to take user (no need to sign up, just click and add details, then submit) input, it is just a plain text field. I know I need to set-up a php to store the new data as people enter it but I am a little lost. I searched but did not see an Q&A already, if it exists a redirect would be great. Thanks in advance!

Here is the page if you'de like to see the source, very basic. http://www.nextepisodepgh.org/worldartproject.html

Comment: So basically anyone could go there and bloat the map with anything they want?

Comment: I am just experimenting at the moment, but yes essentially.

Comment: You could be spammed as hell, just warning you ;)

Comment: I know but as I said this is my first attempt with google maps api

Answer (score 1):

Once the user has clicked on the button you need to do a post back of the form (either directly or indirectly via ajax) to your php page. Your php would simple just grabbed the get or post variable and save it to the database.

Comment: Yeah...I am sure it is a simple php script...just need to learn. Thanks anyways.